# How can I write "tchi"

Tags: katakana, orthography, rōmaji

As in title, how can I write "tchi" in katakana as in the word "hotchikisu" (paper fastener)?

Comment: hotchikisu - ホッチキス use ッ .

Answer (score 3):

It's "cchi".

And if you want to write just a small "tsu" (っ) type in "xtu".

Comment: Well, this is true on most (?all) input systems built in Japan, which do not accept Hepburn romanisation (for reasons which are not entirely clear, as there is no reason they shouldn't). But it's actually shorter to avoid non-Hepburn, and use kunrei, which is 'tti'.

Answer (score 2):

You could write ホッチキス. Small ツ (ッ) is 促音.

Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokuon